# jquery slidetoggle query

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a drop down function of list results using the jquery slide method.

The problem i am having is that when the user clicks on the 'category' class, it expands and shows the 'forms' for all the categories. Not just the one that has been clicked on. Can anybody suggest why?

My HTML:

```
<div id="categoryloop">
    {% for c in Category_Name %}
    <li class="categories">{{ c.Name }}
        <ol>
            {% for form in c.form_set.all %}
            <li class="forms"><a href="/forms/{{ form.id }}">{{ form.Title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}</ol>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".categories").click(function(){
    $(".forms").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)..or use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) so it knows to only open a specific one

```
$(".categories").click(function(){
    $(".forms",this).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

or

```
$(".categories").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".forms").slideToggle("fast");
});
```